# Call a method inside a method in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have methods:

```
methods: {
  submit () {
    this.loading = true
    setTimeout(function () {
      this.loading = false
      this.success() // how to call success() ?
    }, 3000)
  },
  success() {
    this.$store.dispatch('Auth/register', this.register)
  }
}
```

How do I call `success()`? My error `this.after` is not a function

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the `this` context:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  this.loading = false
  this.success();  // this is fine
}, 3000)
```

Otherwise the callback function injects its own `this`

Answer (score 0):

Although using arrow function is the best way to achieve this, you can store `this` inside a `const` before calling `setTimeout` method:

```
methods: {
  submit () {
    const _self = this
    _self.loading = true
    setTimeout(function () {
      _self.loading = false
      _self.success()
    }, 3000)
  },
  success() {
    this.$store.dispatch('Auth/register', this.register)
  }
}
```